# Why iOS simulator snapshot is different on every machine

Tags: ios, jenkins, continuous-integration, ios-simulator, gamut

### **Problem:**

I tried to integrate snapshot testing (pointfreeco library).
In my machine it works(Catalina macOS)

Looks like the snapshots taken from different machines, though,have changes although I'm using iPhone 8 & iOS 14.4 when I run them.

### **Possible Solution:**

Device gamut may be what is changing from one machine to the other and hence producing different snapshots.

### **Question:**

Do you have any idea how this can be fixed? Or letting me know if there is any other factor that may cause different output across different machines?